# TFS 2017 Extranet Support

Tags: tfs

Is there a document on how to enable extranet access to TFS 2017? I have a VPS that I use and want to enable external access to TFS 2017 that is installed on this VPS.
Thank you

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), particularly the section with the numbered list, specifically item #4 in that list.

Comment: @CMSCPgmr Can you access the VPS from extranet? If not you may need a VPN.

Comment: I found the links you showed below. I cannot access the VPS from extranet so I think I will need to try the VPN. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below methods:

1. Maintain a connection between the client and the server by using a
   VPN if you have to access Team Foundation Server from outside the
   local intranet.
2. Through a Reverse Proxy
3. Locating TFS in an Extranet

Please refer to [Chapter 17 – Providing Internet Access to Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx) for details. It's still available for TFS 2017 even though it's an old document.